# Change children font color on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change font color on click, but unfortunetely it doesnt change. What is the correct way to do it ?

```
$("#hepsi").click(function(){

$(this).removeClass('boskolon2').addClass('boskolon').siblings('.boskolon').removeClass('boskolon').addClass('boskolon2');
$(this).children("img").not("img.profimg").hide();
$(this).children("font").css({color: 'red'});

});
```

html

```
<div id="hepsi" class="boskolon2">
<img class="profimg" src="misal.png" width=36 \><div>
<b><font id="probas">AkifFF</font></b><br>22, Mersin</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: FYI `<font>` was deprecated back when Bill Clinton was president.

Comment: `font` is not a child of `#hepsi`, it's a descendant.

Comment: Don't be a dick. I'm giving you a helpful tip to improve your code and you come back with a dicky comment.

Comment: Your helpfulness can be easily seen from your words. Thanks, don't need your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find()` instead of `.children()`, note `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

```
$(this).find("font").css({"color": 'red'});
```

Answer (score 1):

use toggleClass, when you want to change a color, or some css rule dont do it with js, is slower than css

```
$("#hepsi").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('myColor');
});
```

css code

```
.bosklon {
   color: ...;
 }

.bosklon.myColor{
  color : ...;
 }
```

html

```
<div id="hepsi" class="bosklon">
<img class="profimg" src="misal.png" width=36 \><div>
<b><font id="probas">AkifFF</font></b><br>22, Mersin</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the font tag is not supported in html 5, so I'd use CSS instead font tag, you can use this:
`$(this).children("b").css({color: 'red'});`

and remove font tag.

Cheers